# map.key cannot resolve in Thymleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Thymeleaf HTML

[image]

Controller

[image]

Can not resolve `user.headUrl` and so on
and can not resolve `map.get['user'].headUrl`
how to do it?

Comment: in your control class user defined when ```list != null```  i think that the issue.try to define it in out of if block.

Answer (score 0):

To get key and value from Map. use something like this-

```
 <tr th:each="mapItem : ${map}"
              <td th:utext="${mapItem.key}">Key</td>
              <td th:utext="${mapItem.value.fullName}">Fullname</td>  
              <td th:utext="${mapItem.value.email}">Email</td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: it can run directly although the IDEA prompts error

Comment: then try Adding Thymeleaf support for an existing project.